# Wrong number of answers displayed in questions list

Tags: support, answers

This question currently has one answer

[What is "anti-optimization" about?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31099/what-is-anti-optimization-about)

but is listed as having 2 answers at

https://math.stackexchange.com/

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology?sort=active&pagesize=15

Comment: A probable cause for the bug is that I just zapped a SPAM answer to that question within the past half-hour. So maybe it is some sort of the delay in the database, in which case we could just wait it out.

Comment: I think that this is one of those notorious "denormalized counts" on this site. I noticed this too, about half a day ago, when a bunch of spam bots dropped by. A few hours later the count was okay again. I assume the generic answer to this question was given by Jeff [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/wrong-answer-count-after-an-answer-was-deleted-and-undeleted/1630#1630) "Most counts are denormalized and will be auto-corrected every 24 hours."

Comment: The answer count is now correct for that posting.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, removal of spam answers can affect cached answer counts for a bit.

This is always corrected in time, so just be patient.